# Sort on foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ok, I am trying to put this as best as I can..

I have two tables `message` and `comments` with a normal relationship where `messageId` is foreign key in `comments`.

Now on certain screen I am showing all messages currently ordered by their post date. Here is the twist: what is required now is that although display should be same where only messages should be seen, order should be according to latest comment that is posted on messages.

Example:

- Message 1 and message 2
- Message 1 post date > message 2 post date
- but message2 has received a comment just now.

In that case message 2 should be seen on top of list and then message 1

Note: in display I am not pulling comments and only showing messages order by postdate

I hope I put that right.

Comment: "Message 1 post date > message 2 post date" is it okay? because of Message 2 post after message 1. so message 2 post date is greater then message 1 post date.

Comment: can you post your sql query to display message with coment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT M.*, C.MostRecent
  FROM Message M
  JOIN (SELECT MessageID, MAX(Comment_DateTime) AS MostRecent
          FROM Comments
         GROUP BY MessageID
       ) AS C ON M.MessageID = C.MessageID
 ORDER BY C.MostRecent DESC
```

That works reasonably on small tables.  It summarizes the Comments table, finding the most recent comment for each message, and then ordering the messages in descending order of timestamp.  It gets slow if the tables are big, especially if you are only going to show the top few messsages.  In that case, you want to place limits on the the queries so that much less than the full tables are scanned.  For instance, you can probably guess that you only need rows for the last hour, or day, or week, rather than for all time.

Even with OLAP function notations, you still need to worry about whether you can restrict your queries to useful subsets of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, using a CTE (Common Table Expression) and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT
     m.MessageId, m.MessageText, m.PostedDate,
     CommentDate = ISNULL(c.CommentDate, '19000101'),
     RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.MessageID 
                                 ORDER BY ISNULL(c.CommentDate, '19000101') DESC) 
 FROM dbo.Messages m
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Comments c ON c.MessageId = m.MessageId
)
SELECT
   MessageId, MessageText, PostedDate
FROM 
   CTE
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
ORDER BY
   CommentDate DESC
```

This CTE "partitions" the data by `MessageID`, and then numbers all comments - if any - by their `CommentDate`. So for each `MessageID`, you should get consecutive `RowNum` values - starting at 1 for the most recent comment.

From this CTE (a "temporary" in-line view), you just select all the rows that have `RowNum = 1` - all the rows with the most recent comment date. I am also selecting the `CommentDate` inside the CTE, and since I thinking there might be no comments yet, I'm using the `ISNULL()` function to make sure to provide a ficticiuos comment date if no comments exist.